# Install Elasticsearch through composer

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to install Elasticsearch though composer in my project. But when i run this command

composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch

it showing me an error below

[ErrorException]
file_get_contents(C:\xampp\php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: can you run with Admin / root user.

Comment: Yes, i tried but it return same issue

Comment: Where do you run that command? Also, please don't use elevated permissions to install packages, this only causes more problems

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Permissions issue or Composer issue.

Could you try the following:-

```
echo %COMPOSER%
set COMPOSER=
```